# Deploy ASP.NET to intranet server with host name,keeps asking me for credential

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, credentials, hostname

i am deploying an ASP.NET 4.0 Application to a production server .
The server is an intranet server. In the binding of the site, I assigned an IP Address and a port number and it works fine in the form `http://xx.x.xx.x:888/`. Then I would like our user to use a friendly URL to access to the website.  So I asked our IT manager to assign a friendly URL to this url. the friendly URL is like this `http://sitename.mycompanyname.ca:888`.
The problem is when I try accessing the site with the friendly URL it keeps pop-asking me for my credential and never lets me get into the site. Thanks for your helping.
Server environment:

- Windows 2008
- IIS 7.5
- Server and users are all in intranet.

*Update:

- If I stop the site, it gives me another "Internet explorer cannot display the page" error. So I guess this site **is** taking care of the request for this host name
- I found that I can browse this site using host name if I am on the production server.But it doesn't work if I try on another computer.
- Just found that It doesn't work with IE 9 32 bit but it works with Chrome and firefox, which is very weird...

*

The site's authentication and authorization is like below

[image: The site's authentication and authorization is like this]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you mentioned this, but did you try adding the port to your friendly URL? ie. http://sitename.mycompanyname.ca:888 ?

Let us know!

Ricky

Comment: Yes, I tried. 'http://sitename.mycompanyname.ca:888' is exactly what I used to access and is the one keeps asking me for credential. Thanks. I will edit the question to make it more exact.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in there? That could be what's allowing "localhost" or intranet IPs access with no authentication, but requiring authentication for non-localhost (incoming from outside the intranet) connections.

Comment: sorry,you mean .htaccess  in where ? I don't quite understand. the problem is that `http://xx.x.xx.x:888/` works while `http://sitename.mycompanyname.ca:888` doesn't work. and even if there is such authentication, I still get asked for credential after i specify my correct user name and password.  It doesn't let me in even after i specify my user name and password

Answer (score 0):

Enable anonymous authentication. That's it ;)

http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc770966%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.I need the windows authentication. If I enable the anonymous authentication, My application can't get the right user information.